# Use a javascript SDK in a script tag in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Basically I'm trying to implement an external JDK offered by a third party into my react application. It essentially plugs an interactive map on your page. In the usage guide it's implemented like such:

```
<div class="mapdiv" id="some_id" other_important_content="something"></div>
<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>
```

You just stick that anywhere in your html and it loads up the map in the mapdiv.

Obviously, this isn't how react handles this. I want a map widget component, but how should I include this script? There's no NPM package for it. I'm assuming what happens is the script looks for the div and loads in the relevant content. What is the best practice for handling this in react?

Answer (score 1):

You could just include it in your index.html like this

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script async defer src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>
  <script src="./index.js" async></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or with componentDidMount:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    loadJS(
      "https://example.com/script.js"
    ) 
  }

function loadJS(src) {
  const ref = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0] 
  const script = window.document.createElement("script") 
  script.src = src 
  script.async = true 
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(script, ref) 
}
```